# docker-compose not detecting local images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run an application using docker-compose on a Linux server that already has the images stored locally.

The application consists of two services. Running `docker images` on the server indicates that the images do in fact exist:

```
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
app_nginx            latest              b8362b71f3da        About an hour ago   107MB
app_dash_alert_app   latest              432f03c01dc6        About an hour ago   1.67GB
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  dash_alert_app:
    container_name: dash_alert_app
    restart: always
    build: ./dash_alert_app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -b :8000 dash_histogram_daily_counts:server


  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - dash_alert_app
```

When I run, `docker-compose pull` it seems to be able to see the images, and pulls them in:

```
$ sudo docker-compose pull
Pulling dash_alert_app ... done
Pulling nginx          ... done
```

But when I try to spin up the containers I get the following suggesting that the images still need to be built:

```
$ docker-compose up -d --no-build
ERROR: Service 'dash_alert_app' needs to be built, but --no-build was passed.
```

Note that I've configured docker to store images in `/mnt/data/docker` - here is my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file:

```
{
    "graph": "/mnt/data/docker",
    "storage-driver": "overlay",
    "bip": "192.168.0.1/24"
}
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
.
│   docker-compose.yml 
└───dash_alert_app
└───nginx
```

Why is docker-compose not using the images that exist locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to specify the `image` key. Also, do you really have to build the image again with `docker-compose build` or are the existing ones sufficient? If they are, please try this:

```
version: '3'

services:

  dash_alert_app:
    image: app_dash_alert_app
    container_name: dash_alert_app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -b :8000 dash_histogram_daily_counts:server


  nginx:
    image: app_nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - dash_alert_app
```

Comment: The existing images are sufficient - I tried your solution and it worked. Thanks! I find it confusing that these image keys are required, since the application runs locally on my windows machine fine without them.